# Spark GC time is very high causing task execution slow

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I am running spark application on 5 node cluster. Each node have configuration as 16 core and 64 GB ram.

There are 4 stages in my application. 3 stages executed fast for 4th stage ie mapToPair is it taking too much time(almost 4 hours).

Below is the job statistics for job[image: Executors GC Time]

I have checked executors logs as well, didn't see any errors/exception. Could you please suggest me if any configuration changes needs to be done to improve the performance?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning

Comment: If you still want help, could you add your specific config?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to repartition the dataframe inside the application and increase cores, with partitons = cores and check again.

Answer (score -3):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html

first try
`.config("spark.executor.memory","8g")`

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html

Comment: Why would you up the executor memory to 8g? Under executors tab it shows Storage Memory to be 49.2 KB/3.6 GB.